# Parametrized object cannot be resolved to variable

Tags: java, parameters

I have this piece of code:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void put(K key,V value){
        if(this.containsKey(key)){
            TableEntry<K,V> foundKey = (TableEntry<K,V>)this.getTableEntry(key);
            foundKey.setValue(value);
        } else{
            int slotNumber = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % size;
            TableEntry<K,V> candidate = (TableEntry<K,V>) elements [slotNumber];
        }

        // empty slot
        if(candidate == null){
            elements[slotNumber] = new TableEntry(key,value,null);
        }else{
            while(candidate != null){
                candidate = candidate.next;
            }
            candidate.next = new TableEntry(key,value,null);
        }
    }
```

Variables `candidate` and `slotNumber` are underlined in Eclipse, as are the invocations of the `TableEntry()` constructor. Can you tell me why I can't compare for example candidate with null?

If you need, here is complete class (Hash table):

```
package hr.fer.oop.lab3.prob2;

public class SimpleHashtable<K,V> {

    private V[] elements;
    private static int defaultsize = 16;
    private int size;

    public SimpleHashtable(){
        this(defaultsize);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public SimpleHashtable(int initialCapacity){
        if(initialCapacity < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Capacity must be at least 1.");
        }
        elements = (V[])new Object[calculateCapacity(initialCapacity)];
    }

    public int calculateCapacity(int number){
        int result = 2;
        while(result < number){
            result = result << 1;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void put(K key,V value){
        if(this.containsKey(key)){
            TableEntry<K,V> foundKey = (TableEntry<K,V>)this.getTableEntry(key);
            foundKey.setValue(value);
        } else{
            int slotNumber = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % size;
            TableEntry<K,V> candidate = (TableEntry<K,V>) elements [slotNumber];
        }

        // empty slot
        if(candidate == null){
            elements[slotNumber] = new TableEntry(key,value,null);
        }else{
            while(candidate != null){
                candidate = candidate.next;
            }
            candidate.next = new TableEntry(key,value,null);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private TableEntry<K,V> getTableEntry(K key) {
        int slotNumber = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % this.size;
        TableEntry<K,V> candidate = (TableEntry<K,V>) elements [slotNumber];

        while(candidate != null){
            if(key.equals(candidate.getKey())){
                return candidate;
            }
            candidate = candidate.next;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean containsKey(K key) {
        return false;
    }

    private static class TableEntry<K,V>{
        K key;
        V value;
        TableEntry next = null;

        public TableEntry(K key, V value, TableEntry next){
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

        K getKey(){
            return key;
        }

        V getValue(){
            return value;
        }

        void setValue(V value){
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Key:" + (String)key + "Value:" + (String)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your declarations of the `candidate` and `slotNumber` variables are visible only within the innermost block containing them, which in this case contains nothing else.  It looks like you want to move the code that uses those variables into that block (as opposed to moving the declarations out of it):

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void put(K key, V value){
        if (this.containsKey(key)) {
            TableEntry<K, V> foundKey = this.getTableEntry(key);
            foundKey.setValue(value);
        } else {
            int slotNumber = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % size;
            TableEntry<K,V> candidate = (TableEntry<K, V>) elements[slotNumber];

            // empty slot
            if (candidate == null) {
                elements[slotNumber] = new TableEntry<K, V>(key, value, null);
            } else {
                while (candidate != null) {
                    candidate = candidate.next;
                }
                candidate.next = new TableEntry<K, V>(key, value, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After your editions, I get message: candidate cannot be resolved to variable

Comment: Only if there is a separate, underlying error.  Always debug Java compile errors from top to bottom.  Indeed, it appears that you have some confusion about the type of the elements of array `elements`: you declare it to be `V`, but apparently assume it to be `TableEntry<K, V>`.  Type erasure probably makes that work in practice, but the compiler might nevertheless object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare then - nor access them at all - at those locations because they're out of scope.  You have declared them within the 'else' part of your if-statement, so that's their scope.

So, solutions are to either move the declaration outside the if, or move your code to inside that 'else' code block.  Which you choose depends on whether you want to access 'slotNumber' or 'candidate' subsequently;  if not, then personally I'd prefer the second, so :

```
    if(this.containsKey(key)){
        TableEntry<K,V> foundKey = (TableEntry<K,V>)this.getTableEntry(key);
        foundKey.setValue(value);
    } else{
        int slotNumber = Math.abs(key.hashCode()) % size;
        TableEntry<K,V> candidate = (TableEntry<K,V>) elements [slotNumber];

        // empty slot
        if(candidate == null){
            elements[slotNumber] = new TableEntry(key,value,null);
        }else{
            while(candidate != null){
                candidate = candidate.next;
            }
            candidate.next = new TableEntry(key,value,null);
        }
    }
```